# Delete a nested array or PSCustomObject from an ArrayList

Tags: arrays, powershell, .net-core, arraylist

I don't get why this is not working, but I would like to understand what is going on here?

Suppose that I have an ArrayList that contains these nested values:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$al = @(@(0,1),@(1,2),@(3))
```

And another array that contains this value:

```
$myObj = @(0,1)
```

Why can't I delete $myObj from $al even if $myObj is contained in $al with Remove() method?

$al.Remove($myObj)

Thanks!

I did this with simple object type like int or string and it works perfectly fine. I think this has something to do with array equality or because arrays are reference type... but how can I achieve the deletion?

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I delete `$myObj` from `$al` even if `$myObj` is contained in `$al` with `Remove()` method?

Because **Arrays** are [**Reference Types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-7.3#43-reference-types) and `$myObj = @(0,1)` **is not** a reference of the `@(0,1)` in `$al`.

See [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.remove?view=net-8.0#remarks) on `ArrayList.Remove(Object)`:

> This method determines equality by calling [Object.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-8.0).

And, looking at **Remarks** in the `Object.Equals` doc we can read the following:

> If the current instance is a reference type, the `Equals(Object)` method tests for reference equality, and a call to the `Equals(Object)` method is equivalent to a call to the [ReferenceEquals method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-8.0). Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to the same object.

You could for example try and find the object in `$al` that matches structurally your `$myObj` and from there your remove would work.

```bash
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $al = @(@(0, 1), @(1, 2), @(3))
$myObj = @(0, 1)
$toRemove = $al | Where-Object {
    [System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual([int[]] $myObj, [int[]] $_)
}
$al.Remove($toRemove)
```

Comment: I reviewed how can I do this in a better fashion and instead of trying to delete the entry in the ArrayList, I overwritten the table by filtering it out. This now works like a charm.